# Google Sheets: current date when paste new row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sorry for my poor English.

I need the current date to automatically appear when I insert a new row by copy-paste from another sheet or table into column C. The TODAY() function is not suitable because A fixed date is required.

I created a table as a sample. I need that when copying a row from the “Just for example-copy row from here” sheet into the “Operational Sheet”, a fixed current date appears in column C.

Table link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18rF449WUy4DhoSypdt5ZBoJ3K0_k-7aKZozxWcFkkkY/edit?usp=sharing

I am a complete novice in writing scripts, I can only copy and slightly modify other scripts.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if(col === 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Operational Sheet"){
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+9:00", "dd.MM.yyyy"));
}
}
```

I have this script, but it only works when changing a cell manually, not when copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, the 1st sheet name was `Operational sheet`. That is not `Operational Sheet`. So, when your showing script is used, I'm worried that `col === 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Operational Sheet"` always returns `false`. Please be careful about this.
- About `I have this script, but it only works when changing a cell manually, not when copying and pasting.`, in this case, I guessed that you might have wanted to copy and paste multiple rows.

When these points are reflected in a sample script, how about the following script?

#### Modified script:

Before you test this script, please confirm your sheet name again.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheetName = "Operational sheet"; // Please confirm your sheet name again.

  var { range } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.columnStart != 1 || sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName) return;
  sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, 3, range.rowEnd - range.rowStart + 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+9:00", "dd.MM.yyyy"));
}
```

- In this sample script, when multiple rows are copied to "Operational sheet" sheet from column "A", the value of `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+9:00", "dd.MM.yyyy")` is put into column "C" of the copied rows.

#### Note:

- If you want to put the date to columns "C" only when columns "A" and "B" have the values in the copied rows, please test the following script.

  ```js
  function onEdit(e) {
    var sheetName = "Operational sheet"; // Please confirm your sheet name again.

    var { range } = e;
    var sheet = range.getSheet();
    if (range.columnStart != 1 || sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName) return;
    var values = range.getDisplayValues();
    var rowStart = range.rowStart;
    var ranges = values.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
      if (r.every(e => e)) {
        ar.push(`C${i + rowStart}`);
      }
      return ar;
    }, []);
    if (ranges.length == 0) return;
    sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+9:00", "dd.MM.yyyy"));
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: OMG it worked perfectly! You literally saved me. After several days of searching for clues, I can now finish working on the actual table. Thanks to you, this spreadsheet will save me a lot of time throughout the year.

Comment: @Thurman Murman About `OMG it worked perfectly!`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Forgot to click on the accept button. Have a good day, friend!

Comment: @Thurman Murman Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too!